# Why is a required custom (user or group) column not working in the document information panel of Word 2013?

Tags: content-type, person

In the OOTB document library "Documents" I added a new column "Author". This column is from the type "user or group". It is also required. When I create a new document from the ribbon and try to save the document, it asks me to fill in the required fields. I see a red asterik on the field "Author", but I can not enter some value!! What is going wrong?

When I click inside the textbox nothing happen. I cannot type inside the textbox. Lools like it is disabled. There is also some warning "At this moment not available" inside of it.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean, you type but nothing is appearing?

Comment: Yes, I cannot type inside the textbox. Lools like the textbox is disabled. See also my update with the printscreen.

Comment: When you created the columns, did you set any other options to be different than the default.  I have created a number of different user type fields in my test library and haven't been able to recreate your issue.  Have  you tried to delete and re-add the column?

Comment: That's not a DIP, actually, but `Backstage area`. Please follow this https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-open-the-document-information-panel-in-microsoft-word-2010/ to test how that field behaves in DIP. Seems network-related issue to me for now

Answer (score 0):

click on `"Eigenschappen"` or properties. And open the document information panel. This will open the columns above the word file. There you can enter the name correctly.